# Using Pandas and Tweepy do I need to read a json file of tweets line by line

Tags: python, pandas, tweepy

I have the following code that saves tweets to a json file

```
            for tweets in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=account).items(1000):
            # depending on where the supports club are home or away
            if tweets.created_at >= EarliestTweet:
                #Write it to a file
                json.dump(tweets._json,jsonfile, sort_keys = True, skipkeys = True, indent = 2,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Using pandas `dataframe.read_json` do I need to read the json file line by line or is it possible to pass read_json the filename to create a dataframe

Comment: Have you already tried to use `read_json`, and if so, what happened? Data samples are also encouraged for more specific solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.read_json` should return a dataframe. Read docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.read_json.html).

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm struggling to known if my json file is correctly formatted or if I'm calling the read_json with the correct parameters. In some posts I see people add /n after writing a tweet to the file. Do you know if tweepy's _json needs to be read as split ,columns ,records,index or  columns

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is preventing you?

Comment: My problem is given above how I've created the json file how do I read it into a pandas dataframe using read_json? and what params do I need to pass to read_json so tweepy json is read without causing errors

Comment: The parameters you use depends on what you want your final output to me. Simply execute ``pd.read_json(json_here)`` and see what comes out. If it throws an error come back and ask again.

Comment: Thanks @theamateurdataanalyst I got the error ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98283/discussion-between-theamateurdataanalyst-and-michael).